# How to send email notification in ibmdatastage with custom body?

Tags: datastage

I tried to send custom body in data stage notification I don't know how to do that.

I want to send email notification with custom body message in IBM data stage.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Notfication stage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.design.help.doc/topics/notificationpage.html) on Sequence level (in a Sequence job).

Alternatively you could run an OS script sending out an email (sendmail) using a Execute Command stage